# Firefox Dev Tools - Does it have a multiple line console?

Tags: firefox, console.log, firefox-developer-tools

Does Firefox Dev Tools have a setting that allows the console to operate in a multiple line mode? Several of my colleagues have suggested I use Chrome/Opera Dev Tools or, at the very least, Firebug.

**Technical Information**

Firefox Version: 49.0.1 with no add ons.

I **do** primarily use Opera and Opera Development Tools when I write/develop web applications. However, for the sake of cross browser compatibility, it is sometimes necessary to debug applications in specific browsers.

I don't use Firebug, because Firebug is buggy. Firefox's built-in Development tools work better than those in Firebug. Plus, the built-in tools are more stable than those in Firebug.

I'm aware of Firefox's Scratchpad and the Split console mode. Currently, I use the Scratchpad in split console mode to debug things in my web applications when I need more than one line for debugging. However, not being able to see the DOM puts this method at a serious disadvantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't use Firebug, because Firebug is buggy. Firefox's built-in Development tools work better than those in Firebug. Plus, the built-in tools are more stable than those in Firebug.

Note that Firebug no longer exists as it used to. Firefox is becoming multi-process and Firebug wasn't compatible with it. So now, Firebug and the native DevTools have merged into one.

> Does Firefox Dev Tools have a setting that allows the console to operate in a multiple line mode?

There's no settings for this, but there are 2 ways in which the console will operate in multi-line mode:

- if you press shift+Enter on the keyboard, a new line will be created
- if you create a new block and press enter, a new line will be created too, instead of submitting an invalid JS expression.

For instance, if you enter `let a = {` and then press enter, then the prompt will just go to the next line and let you finish entering the properties of the new object you're creating.
If you then enter `}` on the next line and press enter, then the whole `let a = { }` expression will be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

According to Firefox's Web Console Keyboard Shortcuts page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Keyboard_shortcuts#Command_line_interpreter) you can enter multiple line expressions in the console using the "Shift + Return (Enter)" button.

There isn't a setting to put the console in multiple line mode, because Firefox Development Tools doesn't need such a setting.

Comment: are you able to elaborate on the statement "because Firefox Development Tools doesn't need such a setting"